# Preventing gaps/borders when using texture for sprite sheet

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures

I am using textured quads to render a grid of tiles from a sprite sheet. Unfortunately when rendered, there are small gaps between the individual tiles:

[image: visual gaps between tiled quads]

Changing the texture parameters to scale the texture using GL_NEAREST rather than GL_LINEAR fixes this, but results in artifacts within the textured quad itself. Is there some way to prevent GL_LINEAR from interpolating using pixels outside of the specified UV coordinates? Any other suggestions for how to fix this?

For reference, here's the sprite sheet I am using:

[image: tile sheet that causes gaps]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a precision problem with your texture maps, are you using floats (32bit) or something smaller ? And how do you calculate the coordinates ?

Also leaving a 1 pixel border between texture sometimes helps (sometimes you always get a rounding error).

Myself I use this program http://www.texturepacker.com/ (not affiliated in any way), and you get the texture map and UV coordinates from it, you can also specify a padding around the textures and it can also extrude the last color around your texture, so even if get weird rounding probs you can always get a perfect seam.

I would check your precision and calcs first though.

Comment: I'm using floats, and calculating the uv coordinates by simply dividing the x and y integer tile coordinates by 8.0f. u=tile_x/8.0f; u+1=(tile_x+1)/8.0f;. I'm pretty sure it's a problem with the texture filtering, which doesn't properly clamp the texture when specifying an internal tile. Adding borders to each tile seems the only reasonable way to go at the moment, though it's strange since I don't see this done in the sprite sheets of other programs.

Comment: That program I wrote about in my answer has those two options to correct for these problems, so it must happen in some situations, but never happened to me as well.